# Magento 2 - Grid.phtml override of Catalog Widget Vendor Module

Tags: php, overriding, magento2

I want to make changes in "grid.phtml" file which is in the bellow file path at vendor side in Magento 2. path for file which need to override - " module-catalog-widget/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml".

With the help of Extension or Theme I want to override this file and want to add changes.

- Thank for helping in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

To override this file you can copy this grid.phtml and move it into your theme path will be :

> app/design/frontend/{theme_package}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog_Wiget/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml

Please generate compile

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
```

and don't forget to clear cache

```
bin/magento cache:clear
```

Comment: I tried this solution but it was not working. if possible could you tell me the solution that, with help of extension how can this file be override?
- And Thanks for this solution -[@Fawad Saboor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12182270/fawad-saboor)

Answer (score 0):

> You can try the blow method inside your theme.

```
app/design/frontend/{theme_package}/{theme}/Magento_CatalogWidget/templates/product/widget/content/grid.phtml
```